# req.query coming up empty in node.js after sending data in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, passport.js

I want to push additional data to the db after user logs in, and am using Passport to handle user authentication/sessions. I'm passing in the data correctly in the URL, and when the user clicks on a button, it's redirected to the login screen with all the data. For some reason, when I try to parse out the brand, image, and size variables, it gives me undefined.

Here is how I pass my URL:

```
res.redirect('/login?brand='+ encodeURIComponent(brandToFind) + '&size=' + encodeURIComponent(size_result) + '&image=' + encodeURIComponent(image_url));
```

When the user logs in, here is the functionality that is called:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {failureRedirect : '/login'}), 
function(req,res) {
  var user = req.user; 
  var brand = req.query.brand; 
  var size = req.query.size; 
  var image = req.query.image; 
  console.log("brand: "+ brand); 
  if (user) {
      var email_user = user.local.email; 
        var user_id = user._id; 
        User.update({'local.email': email_user} , { $push: { 'favorite_shoes': { 'brand': brand, 'size': size, 'image_url': image}}} , function(error) {
            if (error) return error;   
            console.log('Added %s with size=%s', brand, size);
          }); 
          req.flash('postAddFavs', 'Saved to Favorites!'); 
          res.redirect('/favorites'); 
    }
   });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your flow confused me. where is res.redirect('/login?brand=xx&size=yy') executed? server side? using express? when it get executed, after login success?

Comment: I guess it should be `app.get` instead of `app.post`